# Wordpress: Is there a way to use PHP code when editing a page as HTML?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress page that have a section that was written as HTML code. But I would like to call some php function inside that HTML. 
Is that posible? When I tried to do that, the PHP code was ignored. The reason I want to use the PHP code is to call an image that is in my template folder.

If that is not the case, Is there a way to call an image from the wordpress uploads using HTML code when I'm editing a page?

Comment: as an alternative, you can add a shortcode that does the PHP process you want to do

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use image tag and image url and embed it in html

```
<img src="https://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/banner_1.png">
```

You can get image link by clicking media in wordpress get link.